# In a multinomial naive Bayes classifier, is the feature vector always a histogram?

Tags: categorical-data, natural-language, naive-bayes

In the [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier#Multinomial_naive_Bayes), the feature vector is defined as a histogram, as well as in this popular and well-done [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/O2L2Uv9pdDA?t=85).

However, if the features are words, then the variable is nominal and, therefore, the distribution cannot be estimated by a histogram (rather, it would be a bar chart).

Are these two sources wrong?

**Edit: I've added the time code for the video**

Comment: Sorry, but I see the opposite in the article:
"A feature vector x = ( x1, … , xn) is then a histogram, with xi counting the number of times event i was observed in a particular instance."
So it is n features for one instance.

Comment: my bad (I guess I should switch off!) you are right $x$ is a barplot.

Comment: So your initial answer was correct: calling it a histogram is an abuse of terminology. I was doubting because I saw this in two "reliable" sources.

Comment: sure, I re-updated the answer. I got confused by $n$, which we typically reserve for the sample size.

Answer (score 1):

As ${\bf x} = (x_1,\ldots,x_n)$  and $x_i$ represent the number of times the instance/word $i$ realizes, then the vector $x$ is a vector of counts.

Thus, yes, ${\bf x}$ would be a barplot and not a histogram.

Comment: What does "However, no Wikipedia is correct" mean?

Comment: @jbowman: it was a typo of course. corrected.